# Thread 1: EXC Breakpoint when deleting a Core Data Record

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, exc-bad-access

I have a group of items stored in Core Data, called Expenses which are grouped in something called an expense. Now when I delete a collection, I want all the expenses inside that collection to also delete and imply the following code:

```
 if editingStyle == .delete{
        let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Collection", message: "All expenses in this collection will also be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            self.collections = CoreDataHelper.retrieveCollections()
        }))

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

            let collection = self.collections[indexPath.row]
            print(self.collections[indexPath.row].title!)
            for expense in self.collectionExpensesDelete{
                if expense.collection == self.collections[indexPath.row].title{
                    if let expenseDeleter = self.collectionExpensesDelete.index(of: expense) {
                        self.collectionExpensesDelete.remove(at: expenseDeleter)
                        CoreDataHelper.deleteExpense(expense: expense)
                    }
                }
            }
            CoreDataHelper.deleteCollection(collection: collection)
            self.collections.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.collections = CoreDataHelper.retrieveCollections()
            CoreDataHelper.save()
        }))
```

and this code works, however whenever I go to my main page, I get an error of Thread 1: BAD Exception and it crashes the app. When I reopen the app, the expense is deleted but it only works after the app crashes. Here is the code that I use and where I get the error;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    let row = indexPath.row

    let expense = expenseFiltered[row]

    CoreDataHelper.save()

    var expenseAmountDisplayed:String = ExpensesAdditions().convertToMoney(expense.amount)

    cell.expenseLabel.text = expense.name
    cell.expenseLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.expenseAmount.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    cell.expenseCategory.text = expense.category
    cell.expenseCollection.text = expense.collection

    var finalDisplayed:String = expense.currencySymbol! + " " + expenseAmountDisplayed
    cell.expenseAmount.text = finalDisplayed

    if expense.expense {
        cell.expenseAmount.textColor = UIColor.red
    }else if expense.income {
        cell.expenseAmount.textColor = UIColor(red:0.49, green:0.83, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
    }

    if !expense.credit && expense.expense{
        cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Expense Icon")
    }
    else if !expense.credit && expense.income{
        cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Income Icon")
    }
    else if expense.credit && expense.income{
        cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Income Icon")
    }
    else if expense.credit && expense.expense{
        cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Expense Icon")
    }

    return cell

}
```

I think it is a problem with reading the expenses but don't understand why because once an expense has been removed from memory, it shouldn't be there any more. The error comes on the line:

```
var finalDisplayed:String = expense.currencySymbol! + " " + expenseAmountDisplayed
```

Comment: What message do you get in Xcode's debug console at the time of the error?

Comment: Nothing, the error just comes and the app stops working.

Comment: This may not have anything to do with your issue, but you are calling `CoreDataHelper.save()` ***every time*** `cellForRowAt` is called??? Sounds like a very bad idea... Is it an async function? Is that possibly also changing the data in the background? In any case, you are explicitly unwrapping `expense.currencySymbol!` on the line where the crash is happening. If you temporarily replace that with `X` (a "fake" symbol), does the crash go away?